# git Pull уделенной ветки в локальную?

Tags: git, git-pull

Задача вроде проста, но есть сомнения, не хочется эксперименты проводить на рабочем проекте) локальная ветка "A"  наследования от dev, мне нужно подтянуть в нее изменения из другой удаленной ветки "B", которая также наследована от dev. Правильно ли я понимаю, что команда git pull origin "B", это то что мне нужно ,таким образом я получу изменения из ветки "B" в текущую ветку "A"? Спасибо!

Comment: git merge для слияния веток

Comment: Сделайте `git clone` в отдельную папку и там экспериментируйте. Это не затронет текущую рабочую папку. После этого новую папку с клоном удаляете и все.

Comment: "не хочется эксперименты проводить на рабочем проекте" --- ничто не мешает создать новую папочку вне проекта и там инициализировать гит и поэкспериментировать в пустом "проекте"

Comment: @RomanKonoval, зачем `clone`, если можно просто скопировать локально, без обращения по сети? Это же быстрее

Answer (score 0):

Так как `git pull` = `git fetch`+`git merge`, можно (а при наличии сомнений даже нужно) выполнить отдельно `git fetch`, а дальше спокойно мержить.